# How to make a relative reference in an array formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Here's the straightforward version of my question:

I want to change the following formula to an array formula...

Original formula (from cell J2):

```
=if(F4="VM:",G4,J1)
```

My attempt at converting to an array formula (in cell K1):

```
=arrayformula(if(row(A:A)=1,G3,if(F:F = "VM:",G:G,indirect("K"&row(A:A)-1))))
```

This works on rows where F = "VM:", but returns a #REF error on other rows.  Function INDIRECT parameter 1 value is 'K0'. It is not a valid cell/range reference.

Thoughts on how to fix this?

---

The more complex version of my question.  i.e. Why am I trying to do this?...

I have a weird spreadsheet with data that should really be in a Wiki.

I want to create filter views for each person so they can easily filter on only their own vendors.  The original formula will work, but as more vendors are added, I'd like for the formula to automatically work for those rows as well.

If there's a better way to do this, I'm listening.

[image]

Comment: You have to change sharing setting for your sample - it yells: "Access Denied"

Comment: Shoot.  It's only giving me the option to share within my company.  I've attempted to add a screen shot.  That may help.

Comment: It would be easier to have a screenshot that includes columns and rows headers... :)

Comment: Oops.  I updated the screenshot.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly understand your needs, but If you want to autopopulate your formula, then you only need this code in desire column in row 4 (you can change this to any other - this will autofill down from this point):

```
=ArrayFormula(if(F4:F="VM:",G4:G,J1:J))
```

Is this what you are trying to get?

## After clarification:

You need this code in J2 only:

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(ROW(J2:J),
  QUERY({F:G,ROW(G:G)},"select Col3,Col2 where Col1='VM:'",1)
,2,1)
)
```

[image]

Works for you?

Comment: That's close, but it's giving me a circular dependency error when I put it in column J.  The goal is to replace the formula that's currently in column J with one that will update automatically as new rows are added.  I tried changing the iterative calculation settings, but that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you just need to hide errors?

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A:A)=1,G3,IF(F:F = "VM:",G:G,INDIRECT("K"&ROW(A:A)-1)))),)
```